# Fastest Way To Populate Data From DataTable To DataSet

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable, datacolumn

I'm try to populate data from DataTable to Dataset through a foreach loop (rows and columns).

I see that on each round , time is growing up.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    stopwatch.Start();
    ds.Namespace = "http://www.schema.co";
    stdTable = new DataTable("param");

    col1 = new DataColumn("key");
    col2 = new DataColumn("value");
    stdTable.Columns.Add(col1);
    stdTable.Columns.Add(col2);
    ds.Tables.Add(stdTable);

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        stopwatchcolumn.Start();
        DataRow newRow;
        newRow = stdTable.NewRow();
        newRow["key"] = col.ColumnName;
        if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            newRow["value"] = DateTime.Parse(row[col].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            newRow["value"] = row[col].ToString();
        }
        stdTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        newRow = stdTable.NewRow();
        stopwatchcolumn.Stop();
        mainLog.WrLInfo("ELAPSED COLUMNS", stopwatchcolumn.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    mainLog.WrLInfo("ELAPSED", stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    ds.AcceptChanges();
}
```

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011310

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011394

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011510

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011608

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011701

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011789

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011910

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0011999

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0012306

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0012399

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0012492

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0012604

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0012697

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0012786

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0012888

2019-08-20 12:50:05 INFO:

[ELAPSED COLUMNS] 00:00:00.0013158

Comment: you know that `if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime)) x = DateTime.Parse(row[col].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` is redundant? and casting is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your code measuring time is wrong, in the line

```
mainLog.WrLInfo("ELAPSED COLUMNS", stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
```

you should use stopwatchcolumn instead of stopwatch so just correct this

```
mainLog.WrLInfo("ELAPSED COLUMNS", stopwatchcolumn.Elapsed.ToString());
```

and use Reset method after stopping stopwatch.

Comment: my problem on time grow up still exist

Comment: @Aleksey you should use StartNew() instead of Start, you are not resetting your old measure or use Reset method after Stop

Comment: hey, thnx  changet it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are creating a separate table for each row of original table.  There are a lot better ways of putting all the data into one table.  Here is the code I would use

```
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        stdTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { col.ColumnName, DateTime.Parse(row[col].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stdTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { col.ColumnName, row[col].ToString() });
                    }
                }
```